# Google Apps Marketplace JAR and GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jar, google-eclipse-plugin, google-apps-marketplace

When you use the Google-Eclipse plugin to create a new **Web Application Project**, and you select the option to "*Add support for listing on Google Apps Marketplace*", the plugin automatically adds an `apps-marketplace.jar` file on your classpath.

Does this - at *any* point in time, for *any* reason - ever need to be bundled with your WAR? I ask because it contains a bundled version of SLF4J that is causing JAR hell issues with other dependencies that use a different version of SLF4J.

I bundled it into my WAR because I thought it was necessary, but if its something that is just used by the plugin, or is perhaps available as some service to GAE apps when they're running in production, then I don't need it and would like to remove it as a dependency. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This jar is not needed. You can remove it from your build path and your WAR directory. We need to fix the plugin so that it gets rid of this jar.

I have a feeling it was first added in to make it easy to access certain Google APIs from your Marketplace app. It included a bunch of classes for handling OAuth. However, I think that all of the classes in here are basically deprecated, and there are better ways to make these Api calls now.